# tensorflow seq2seq model outputting the same output

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm, encoder-decoder

I am developing an encoder-decoder model in order to predict titles for lecture transcripts. but the model is predicting the same title no matter what the input is. Any idea what may have caused such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to solve this, I will strongly recommend you to provide your code as an example, better including your loss, accuracy or something people will be more familiar about your problem. However, here are some conditions that will run into that problem: **1) your code was not doing the things you would like to do somehow**. **2)** LSTM sometimes experience **gradient explode or gradient vanish** problem, although it was said to fix those problem that a RNN structure will face, it still get into that problem form time to time anyway. **3)** forget to **shuffle** your dataset before training, which makes your model learn the same pattern of one kind all the time. If all the things that mentioned above did not fit in your case, try to provide your code and dataset information to make it clear.